# Problems with Game Center Leaderboards

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have an app that has already approved by Apple for about 24hrs and pending developer release on the App Store and I'm having some weird problems with the Game Center leaderboards. The leaderboards were working fine during testing in sandbox mode, in the approved App Store build, Game Center is enabled but it is still showing the leaderboard status as "NOT LIVE". Using generated promo codes I installed the app on my own device and the leaderboards work perfectly, scores post and show up instantly, but anyone else I have given a promo code to their scores do not post to the leaderboards and they only score that shows up on the leaderboard is mine. Why does my account(same account as my developer account) work perfectly for posting scores but no one elses scores post? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Apple Account Support. We have no information or access to your account or the status of your application. Contact Apple directly via the contact links on their site.

Answer (score 0):

The leader boards will change to "LIVE" once you release.